# Web Api controller routing

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a ConfigurationController with the default routing specified in the static Register method

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The POST method of this endpoint creates a new configuration with a string id which is accessible via the url - 'api/configuration/newid'.

Each configuration can have a 'Task' associated with it. I would now like to expose CRUD operations for the task via the 'TaskController'. So if I want to create a new task for 'newid' I can do it by POSTing at 'api/configuration/newid/task'

I have no clue how to specify the routing for this in my Web API project.

- What should the routing look like?
- Also is this the right approach or should I instead expose the tasks via an explicit endpoint 'api/task' although tasks cannot exist in isolation. They are always bound to a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI is set up to be RESTful; that is, you use HTTP Verbs to talk to your controllers as opposed to named actions (i.e., `newconfig`).

So, to go the route you're already going, instead of hitting `api/configuration/newconfig/task`, you might just hit `api/configuration` and send requests with an HTTP `POST` verb.  Then, the message you send might include what you're creating, for example:

```
{
  type: 'Task',
  data: {
  }
}
```

However, it would be a better idea to separate `Tasks` into their own controller, i.e., `TasksController`, with their own `GET, PUT, POST, DELETE` verbs that act only on `Tasks`.  Then, you would create new `Tasks` by calling `api/Tasks/` with the message body being your desired task.

Comment: I don't particularly like the idea of a separate 'task' endpoint since tasks don't have an independent existence. By 'newconfig' I mean the newly generated id after POSTing to 'api/configuration'.

Answer (score 0):

*What should the routing look like?*

```
routeTemplate: "api/configuration/{id}/task"
```

*Also is this the right approach or should I instead expose the tasks via an explicit endpoint 'api/task' although tasks cannot exist in isolation. They are always bound to a configuration.*

I think you've answered this when you state `Each configuration can have a 'Task' associated with it.`

If you keep your controllers 'light' and ensure the business logic is held somewhere else, adding new routes/controllers/actions becomes trivial.

If you wanted to, you could keep this in a `ConfigurationTasks` controller while still having a `Configuration` and `Task` controller.